# iOS: Memory Leak

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks

In a Utilities class, I have the following method:

```
+ (Division *) getNationalDivision
{
    Division *defaultDivision = [[[Division alloc] init] autorelease];
    defaultDivision.Id = 0;
    defaultDivision.name = @"National";

    return defaultDivision;
}
```

I have a division allocted in my app delegate to store the division throughout the app, so in one of my view controllers I have:

```
appDel.currentDivision = [[Utilities getNationalDivision] retain];
```

In the app delegate .h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Division *currentDivision;
```

In the app delegate .m I have:

```
currentDivision = [[Division alloc] init];
```

When I analyze, I get potential leak of an object that points to the above line.  Any ideas?  If I dont retain the national division, it doesnt work.  Also, just to note, everything works fine.  I just want to make sure I am not leaking something.

Comment: How did you declare currentDivision?

Comment: You may want to mention what your `currentDivision` property is defined as. I presume `retain`? In that case, the extra `retain` here is very likely an over-retain. We'll know more with the `@property` definition.

Comment: I added the code, I am allocating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you declare the property `currentDivision` in your app delegate. If it is `assign` (which I suppose, since you are retaining it before assigning through the property) then the original value you assigned to it:

```
 currentDivision = [[Division alloc] init];
```

will not get `released` when you execute:

```
 appDel.currentDivision = [[Utilities getNationalDivision] retain];
```

hence, the object you created in the app delegate will leak. Do a release manually and check whether the analyzer keeps complaining:

```
[app.currentDivision release];
```

This only makes sense in case your property is declared as `assign`.

In case it is declared as `retain`, then the fault is on line:

```
 appDel.currentDivision = [[Utilities getNationalDivision] retain];
```

where you should not do the retain manually.

Answer (score 2):

The retain is done by the synthesized property accessor method. Remove it.

Comment: He says it doesn't work if he removes retain. So it probably isn't being retained as a property... @Jesse: please provide more info on how you define currentDivision property (or is it a local variable...)

Comment: and if you use [appDel setCurrentDivision:[Utilities getNationalDivision]];?